# Detecting unconfirmed users during sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise with the confirmable module. 
When unconfirmed users are trying to login, I want to be able to detect that and
show the appropriate message.

There's a user.confirmed? function, but that's after you get the user object, I don't get 
it when unconfirmed users are trying to login.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it, Devise sets the flash[:alert] upon unconfirmed user:

flash[:alert] = "You have to confirm your account before continuing"